# How to add class to header element if its href is contained within window href?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, href

My current code applies a class to the proper header element if its `href` is an `indexOf` the `window.location.href`

```
$(function() {
    $('.sidebar-links li.active').removeClass("active");
    $('.sidebar-links li a').filter(function(){
        return this.href.indexOf(window.location.href) !== -1;
            }).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

An example header href would be
http://localhost:8090/website/jobs.php
If my `window.location.href` matches that exactly, it works great. The issue that I am running into is, if I click on something that produces a query string like
http://localhost:8090/website/jobs.php?info=54
Then refresh the page, the header element no longer has the class.
Is it possible to change the function so that if the header element's href  is contained within the `window.location.href` that it will add the class? Or without the query string at all?
http://localhost:8090/website/jobs.php
http://localhost:8090/website/jobs.php?info=54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the URL parameters using: `url.replace(/\?.*/,'')`

In your code, change `this.href.indexOf(window.location.href) !== -1` to `this.href.indexOf(window.location.href.replace(/\?.*/,'')) !== -1`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href.split('?')[0]` for a quick hack,

or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams

If you want a more fancy solution

```js
$('.sidebar-links li.active').removeClass("active");
$('.sidebar-links li a').filter(function () {
    return this.href.indexOf(window.location.href.split('?')[0]) !== -1;
}).parent().addClass("active");
```